# How to define a word in a whole sentence as a variable?

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextfield

I want the name (a name in the entry) to be the assigned value of the variable called `enteredName`.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    performAction()
    return (true)
}

func performAction() {      
    if let entry = textField.text {
        if entry == "my name is" + //a name {
            var enteredName = //the name
            print ("Your name is " + enteredName + " .")

        }
    }
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Why is the user typing in the "my name is" part?

Comment: I don't know. I thought it would kind of work that way. I am still at learning swift.

Comment: @Flo, It _can_ work that way, but it's sort of over-complicating things by allowing (or expecting) the user to type in anything more than their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this: it will check that the user uses the right format ("my name is " at the beginning) and will be case insensitive

```
import Foundation

let mySentence = "My NaMe IS GioR GioR"

let mySentenceLowercased = mySentence.lowercased()

let myNameOnly = mySentence.dropFirst("my name is ".count)

if let myNameLowercased = mySentenceLowercased.components(separatedBy: "my name is ").last,
    myNameOnly.lowercased() == myNameLowercased {
    print("Your name is " + myNameOnly) // Your name is GioR GioR
} else {
    print("Input format error. The correct format is: \"My name is [your name goes here]\"")
}
```

if the format is wrong, for example

```
let mySentence = "My NaMe  GioR GioR"
```

the output will be

```
//Input format error. The correct format is: "My name is [your name goes here]"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let defaultText = "my name is"
    let sentence = "My Name IS    Rohit Makwana"
    let lowercaseString = sentence.lowercased()

    if (lowercaseString.range(of: defaultText) != nil) { // If you require default text "my name is"

        let extraName = sentence.dropFirst(defaultText.count)
        let name = extraName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)//Remove extra space if it contains

        if name.count > 0 {
            print("Your name is " + name) // Your name is Rohit Makwana
        }
        else {
            print("Input format error. The correct format is: \"My name is [your name goes here]\"")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Input format error. The correct format is: \"My name is [your name goes here]\"")
    }
```